# Unpack 16-bit integer values from a 64-bit field in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation, bit-packing

I am reading data from an accelerometer, which provides the measurements for each of the 3 axes (x, y, and z) as 16-bit integers packed into a single 64-bit field.

I have the following code in C to extract these 3 axis values:

```c
uint8_t byte0 = *somevalue*, byte1 = *somevalue*, byte2 = *somevalue*, byte3 = *somevalue*, byte4 = *somevalue*, byte5 = *somevalue*;
uint64_t xyzDataReg = ((uint64_t) byte0<<40) + ((uint64_t) byte1<<32) + ((uint64_t) byte2<<24) + ((uint64_t) byte3<<16) + ((uint64_t) byte4<<8) + (uint64_t)byte5;
int16_t xRaw = (int16_t)((xyzDataReg >> 32) & 0xFFFF);
int16_t yRaw = (int16_t)((xyzDataReg >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
int16_t zRaw = (int16_t)(xyzDataReg & 0xFFFF);
```

But now I need to convert this code into MATLAB. How do I write these bit manipulation operations in MATLAB?

Comment: That comment you got, that code-translation is off-topic for Stack Overflow, was incorrect. Undeleting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Translate the code directly, using [`bitshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html) and [`bitand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html).
2. Use [`typecast`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) on the 64-bit array to convert it to a 16-bit array, then read out the values by indexing:

   ```matlab
   a = uint64(1234567890);
   a = typecast(a, 'int16');
   x = a(3);
   y = a(2);
   z = a(1);
   ```

   Note that the order of the elements depends on the endianness of your architecture.

Comment: Tested and works like charm. Thanks.

Comment: For the first approach:
`nth_byte = 1; % First uint16 byte
dec2bin(bitand(bitshift(xyzDataReg,16*(1-nth_byte)),255));`

Comment: Note that on earlier versions of MATLAB the typecast( ) call will result in a deep copy of the data, affecting performance. On later versions of MATLAB the typecast( ) call will result in a shared data copy, so performance will be good.